# Model Binding and Validation Errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model-binding

I am using asp.net MVC3 and I am very new to this technology.

My models are designed in such a way that the properties will throw validation errors if the data is invalid. In this case, the properties are not set with invalid data.

When I redisplay my editing-view, validation error messages are shown; however the values that the user previously entered are gone because the model that it is bound to only contains the old-valid data.

For example, say I had a `Person` class and the `Name` property cannot be a null or empty string otherwise it throws a validation exception and prevents the property from being set. Now say the user removes the value from the `Name` property and tries to save the `Person` from the web. A validation exception will be thrown and handled properly to add the error to the `ModelState` so that it is displayed on the screen; however the old value for the `Name` is redisplayed since the invalid, empty string never made it into the property.

I do not know how to solve this problem and any advice on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to create a ViewModel that allowed invalid data to be entered into this. This solution also simplified my ModelBinder classes because it took on most of the work.

Answer (score 1):

My advise is allow invalid data but use validation attributes. You wont save invalid entities so there is no problem and this is the standard approach these days. If you don't want do that, there is no easy solution. Most simple solution would be using the info from Request.Form

Comment: I had this conversation at length many times with my team. I agree with you about allowing invalid data into the models but they do not. If we had implemented your suggested design, validation would have been easier to implement in the other application using these models. While this design ensures our model-objects are valid most of the time, it causes problems because the UI and the underlying model that it is bound to are not in sync. So, we have 2 levels of validation: UI validation and Model validation that are performed. So,I am going to have to find that "no easy" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `IValidatableObject` to performe this kind of validation at server side.

From MSDN [IValidatableObject Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx):

> Provides a way for an object to be invalidated.

Theres an exemple here [Using IValidatableObject Custom Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx), also from MSDN.

Comment: So, my models have a Validate method and I am already displaying the validation errors detected by the server side; however, the old value is being displayed. I added an example to my question to further clarify what my problem is...I'm not sure how the IValidatableObject interface is going to help me solve my problem????

Comment: "My models are designed in such a way that the properties will throw validation errors if the data is invalid. In this case, the properties are not set with invalid data.". Thats the problem, the new value will never be set at the model if its invalid, then only the old value will be showed! Thats why you should implement validation using the interface

Comment: I must be missing something key here. As you said, the IValidatableObject "Provides a way for an object to be invalidated." and has 1 method "Validate". I read through the example that you posted (which demonstrates how to do custom validation); however, I still fail to see how the old data is displayed when using this? I'm sorry, but could you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: To display the old data you should pass back to the view the object if Model.IsValid return false. Google about simple CRUD with ASP.NET mvc!

Comment: I do not want to display the old data. I want to redisplay the information that the user provided. If the Person.Name property originally contained "Frinny". Then user removed everything from the textbox bound to the Name property and hit the save button. A validation exception will be thrown upon calling the set logic of the Person.Name property during binding...so the property will never get set. Now when I return the View with the Person, the old Name reappears with a validation message stating "you have to provide a name" next to it which doesn't make sense because the old name is there